# What is a specific example of how the Shellshock Bash bug could be exploited?

Tags: bash, security, exploit, shellshock-bash-bug

I read some articles ([article1](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/09/24/bash-specially-crafted-environment-variables-code-injection-attack/), [article2](http://blog.erratasec.com/2014/09/bash-bug-as-big-as-heartbleed.html#.VCNWB2QbDBk), [article3](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2014/q3/650)) about the [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29) [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) bug ([CVE-2014-6271](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2014/q3/650) reported Sep 24, 2014) and have a general idea of what the vulnerability is and how it could be exploited. To better understand the implications of the bug, what would be a simple and specific example of how some software could exploit the bug?

Comment: You should ask on [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security and as such is better suitable for http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: For others looking for this info (and maybe seeing this as the first hit in Google): http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68122/what-is-a-specific-example-of-how-the-shellshock-bash-bug-could-be-exploited. I also found http://blog.erratasec.com/2014/09/bash-bug-as-big-as-heartbleed.html a helpful reference.

Comment: This is how to install the ‪#‎ShellShock‬ bug patch in ‪#‎Ubuntu‬.
First, run this on your shell prompt:
$ env var='() { ignore this;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c /bin/true
If you are vulnearble, it echos 'vulnerable'.
If you are vulnerable, simply update with aptitude-get and install bash using these commands:
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install bash

Comment: There are plenty of reports of attempted exploits in the wild; see for instance http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/09/bash-shellshocker-attacks-increase-in-the-wild-day-1.html

Comment: ...basically, just throw exploit code in an HTTP header; if that header is exported to the environment (as is done in CGI) and anything calls a shell (and badly-written code that shells out is pretty damned common, especially in the PHP world), then there you are.